# I am getting Unauthorized 401 error during negotiation request using signalR with angular 4

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub

I am getting Unauthorized 401 error during negotiation request using signal R with angular 4. here is my code

```
  this.connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:53248/signalr', 
    {useDefaultPath: false,
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('access_token')});
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('AuctionHub');
```

Following is the error i am getting while connecting to my AuctionHub. How should i resolve my error. here is my code

```
  private startConnection(): void {  
    this.connection.start({ jsonp: true }).done((data: any) => {  
        console.log('Now connected ' + data.transport.name + ', connection ID= ' + data.id);  
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);  
        this.connectionExists = true;  
    }).fail((error: any) => {  
        console.log('Could not connect ' + error);  
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(false);  
    });  
}
```

here is the error in console.

GET http://localhost:53248/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22auctionhub%22%7D%5D&callback=jQuery33104335158357466735_1532340938485&_=1532340938486 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: any one here to help me out